# What is the right way to prerender Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

It almost works after the following steps:

1. Install the hosted version of `blazorwasm` template app.

   ```
   dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted -o HostedWasm
   ```
2. Copy `_Hosted.cshtml` from `blazorserver` template to the `Pages` folder.
3. Change `endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html")` to `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host")` in `Startup.cs` of the server
4. Change `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` to `<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>` in `_Host.cshtml`

Now if you `dotnet run` the server you will be able to navigate template pages with prerendered HTML.

But, I have two questions:

1. Is it the "right" way to do the prerendering of Blazor WebAssembly? I see nothing about this in the docs.
2. How to share DI between server-side and client-side? Now, if you navigate `/` and then going to `/fetchdata` everything will be fine, but if you then use F5 (e.g *refresh*) on `/fetchdata` path, you will see

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Http'
> on type 'HostedWasm.Client.Pages.FetchData'. There is no registered
> service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.

**To fix it** you need to copy `HttpClient` configuration code from *Client/Program.cs* to *Server/Startup.cs*

Comment: Why you don't follow steps inside https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-a-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ?

Comment: For the second question visit https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9941#issuecomment-490162076

Comment: @AmirhosseinMehrvarzi, I see nothing about WebAssembly in that tutorial. Isn't it built entirely using Blazor Server? I don't want to use SignalR for DOM modifications in my app. Thanks for the issue link!

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Lock's excellent blog post, [Enabling prerendering for Blazor WebAssembly apps](https://andrewlock.net/enabling-prerendering-for-blazor-webassembly-apps/), gives the best instructions, IMO. To repeat his steps here:

1. Add _Host Page, `dotnet new page -o Pages -n _Host --no-pagemodel`
2. Copy Client/wwwroot/index.html into it, keeping `@page` at the top
3. Add tag helper, `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`
4. Replace `<div id="app">` with `<component type="typeof(BlazorApp1.App)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />`
5. Remove `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app")` from Program.cs
6. Add an http client to the server, e.g. `services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>`.

He goes on to link to other blog posts which debate the 'right' to handle the missing HttpClient problem. I think just injecting a client is the 'right' approach. It's a simple solution. The app is only running on the server for a few seconds. The pre-rendered app isn't interactive anyway, so it's not like the user is going to click around a bunch.